# How to fix error: 'vreinterpretq_u32_f64' was not declared in this scope - building with Eigen on Android

Tags: android, c++, c, tensorflow, eigen

I'm trying to build Tensorflow Lite for Android which has Eigen as dependencies.
And during build I get this error:

```
   .../eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/Complex.h:383:83: error: 'vreinterpretq_u32_f64' was not declared in this scope
   Packet2d eq_swapped = vreinterpretq_f64_u32(vrev64q_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_f64(eq)));
                                                                                   ^
```

After some digging, I found out that:

1. vreinterpretq_u32_f64 is indeed not defined within Eigen and that
2. Eigen has only the standard library as dependency

So where exactly does this function supposed to come from? (I do have the standard library included explicitly android-ndk-r17c/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++) am I missing some includes?
Anyone can help me shed some lights on this?

Thanks.

Comment: This should be provided by a header like `arm_neon.h` and Eigen should only try to use it if vectorization is enabled. You should report a bug with your exact setup and a minimal example. You can also explicitly deactivate vectorization in Eigen by compiling with `-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ch but using -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE I get: "tensorflow/lite/kernels/eigen_support.cc:36:1: error: division by zero is not a constant-expression" I suppose I do need vectorize...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `vreinterpretq_u32_f64` and `vreinterpretq_f64_u32` is not defined.
If you look at `Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h` line 604, `vreinterpretq_f64_u64` and `vreinterpretq_u64_f64` is defined.
Considering vector width as 128bits, `vreinterpretq_u32_f64` should cast from f64x2 to u32x4, similarly for `vreinterpretq_f64_u32`

Just add this two definitions after line 604 in `Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h`

```cpp
template <typename T> float64x2_t vreinterpretq_f64_u32(T a) { return (float64x2) a; }
template <typename T> uint32x4_t vreinterpretq_u32_f64(T a) { return (uint32x4) a; }
```

Hope this helps!